# iOS fix data model update

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I made mistake during my app update. I had added one field in entity,and didn't create new model for that change. So my app was updated on appstore, and of course it crash because off

```
 <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
```

Looks like this new filed in entity is 100% sure cause of crash.

Now I have to make update and there is a question:

-model1: myentity without field 'three' in app v1

-model1: myentity with field 'three' in app v2

and now if I create this

-model2: myentity with field 'three' in app v3

will app for people who didn't update app from v1 to v2 will work fine then they update app from v1 to v3.

This database model update works like updating database model version after model version to the top, or when I have 5database models during my app development and someone with app v1 with model1 update to app v5 with model v5 it ignores model v2-4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your explanation but given the fact that you never created a new model then none of the stores out there should have been upgraded so they will all still be the earlier version without the additional field.

So your next update needs to have the original model1 without the new field and another model2 with the new field in it.

This appears to be what will be in your app v3.  except you don't mention that app v3 will have BOTH model1 (without the field) and model2 (with the new field).  Make sure both versions of the Core Data model are included in the app bundle.  They should both appear in the main model package.

Comment: So v3 of app should have model1 without and motel2 with new field. It will work for both people updating from v1 and v2 of app?

Comment: Yes, it should work but you really should test this yourself for both cases to check that it works!

Comment: But how can I test this, I mean, updates? Run on simulator or iPhone v1 v2 v3 in those two combinations? Test made like this will show app behave like in real scenario with app updated via appstore?

Comment: Yes run the first version in the sim, create a database with a few records, then run v3 to make sure the upgrade works. Then clear everything run v1 again, then v2 which should fail but should not corrupt the database, the run v3 to make sure the upgrade does in fact work.

Comment: And I assume of course that you can still build and run v1, v2 and v3 from XCode.

Comment: Yes I can. When I remove field from model1 there is no problem with update from v1 to v3, but v2 will not update to v3 - it crash.